# Find the general solution of $\tan x + \cot 2x =0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> Find the general solution of $\tan x + \cot 2x =0$.

Can I use $\tan 2x$ formula to solve this question?

Comment: Yes you can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\tan(x) + \cot(2x) = \tan(x) + \frac{1-\tan^2(x)}{2 \tan(x)} = \frac{1+\tan^{2}(x)}{2 \tan(x)}$$

So the equation has no solution.

Comment: But why Quora has answers related to this question i.e nπ-π/2? I know that solving this question using tan yields no solution..but when it is solved using sin and cos answer do come..How can it be possible?

Comment: $n\pi - \frac{\pi}{2}$ cannot be a solution, since $\tan$ is not defined at this point, so the expression has no sense.

Comment: Oh! That's right.Thanks a lot

Comment: Can u pls solve tan2x * tanx = 1 for me..My answer is nπ±π/6.

Comment: Seems correct to me.